# Why is the uri for a self hosting application set as localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I recently started looking into Asp.net Web Api self hosting. I'm following this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/Asp-Net-web-api-self-hosting/) and I have two questions based on that.

1. Why is the URI for `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` pointing to localhost?
2. How would I give a website name like I would in IIS for the windows service? Because if I deploy this to a production server, how would the clients call the localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q. Why is the URI for `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` pointing to `localhost`?**

**A.** `localhost` simply just means "this computer". It's typical to do it this way to make the intent clear. Nothing stops you from using an ip address.

**Q. How would I give a website name like I would in IIS for the windows service? Because if I deploy this to a production server, how would the clients call the localhost?**

**A.** You would change from `HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:80")` to `HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://000.000.000:80")` where `000.000.000` is the ip address of the host (the machine you are running the web application on)

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is reserved loopback adres (ea 127.0.0.1) try ping localhost.

The origin is basic networking, it existed before .net
Pinging localhost was quite common to check if your own network card still worked. As it ping 127.0.0.1, is a ping to your own network card. Next step in conectivity issues was pinging your gateway and then some remote IP or so.

A client cannot connect to a remote localhost (it will point its own network card).

in regard to the article, a server listens to its own network card.
unless you have some multiple nic environment with specific routes to follow
but then there is a config file for that.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is the default allocation of Windows, if you want to change the default name binding,

answer is simple just go to

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ folder

you can find as **hosts** file there just open it in notepad, if you want to change the locally hosted name add a new line in that text file like

127.0.0.1 domain name you want to use

for example

127.0.0.1 techdoubts.net

then your localhost will be changed to techdoubts.net
[image]

and one more, add that new name in internet information services website binding also.